# the function in $.getJSON seems to not run

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script defer>
    var results = "";
$.getJSON('local node api ip',function(data){
  results = JSON.parse(data);

});
console.log(results);
var elem = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(elem)
elem.innerHTML = results.word
console.log('hello')
</script>
```

I want to parse the result of a local api but the function doesnt seem to run, and i have placed a console.log and that wasnt run. help!!!!

Comment: Put the `console.log` inside `$.getJSON` callback and then test again..

Comment: thats what i have done but it isnt run @palaѕн

Comment: What error are you getting in browser console or network tab when you make this ajax call?

Comment: @palaѕн no errors, it seems as if it is just not ran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks but the problem seems to be that  none of the code inside of function is run

Answer (score 0):

**// $.getJSON is async. You have to write code in callback. or use async-await**

```
$.getJSON("local node api ip", function(results) {
  //const results = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(results);
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.innerHTML = results.word;
  console.log("hello");
});
```

**// Async Await**

```
(async function() {
  let results = await $.getJSON("local node api ip");
  //results = JSON.parse(data);
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.innerHTML = results.word;
})();
```

// SAMPLE

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/", function(results) {
 var elem = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.innerHTML = results.messages.personalized;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have tried this and none of it was run, including the console.log

Comment: could the issue be that my url is my ip adress:port

Comment: u can check network for error! With asyn await. it will throw errror.

Comment: web.html:15 Uncaught (in promise) {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} this error is raised

Comment: You do not need parse. it will be parse automatically. i have updated solution

Comment: ok thanks for that, but the code still does not run, console doesn't log and element is not created

Comment: i have found the issue with no solution, i am trying to use a local ip node api but how do i use it